# How to unpack and assign the values of an iterated list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of items.

```
my_store = [1, 2]
```

that I would like to assign to a list of strings:

```
my_fruit = ['oranges', 'apples']
```

Only if `my_fruit` is present in `my_basket`:

```
my_basket = ['oranges', 'apples', 'grapes', 'bananas']
```

How do I unpack the list items into the string if the condition returns `True`

**what I tried:**

```
for f in my_fruit:
    if f in my_basket:
        for n in my_store:
            print("total {} is:  {}".format(f, n))
    break
```

**what I got:**

```
total orange is 1
total orange is 2
```

**instead of:**

```
total orange is 1
total apple is 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to loop again if the fruit is present in the basket. You can fetch the index of the fruit and then use that index to find the number of that specific fruit from `my_store`.

This can be done like this.

```
for f in my_fruit:
    if f in my_basket:
        n = my_store[my_fruit.index(f)]
        print("total {} is:  {}".format(f, n))
```

You can achieve the same result using enumerate, which comes with additional advantage that you don't need to fetch  the index from the list again.

It can be done like this

```
for idx, f in enumerate(my_fruit):
    if f in my_basket:
        n = my_store[idx]
        print("total {} is:  {}".format(f, n))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `zip` to iterate `my_fruit` & `my_store`

**Ex:**

```
my_store = [1, 2]
my_fruit = ['oranges', 'apples']
my_basket = ['oranges', 'apples', 'grapes', 'bananas']


for fruit, n in zip(my_fruit, my_store):
    if fruit in my_basket:
        print("total {} is:  {}".format(fruit, n))
```

**Output:**

```
total oranges is:  1
total apples is:  2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate through `my_fruit` and check if item is in `my_basket`:

```
my_store = [1, 2]
my_fruit = ['oranges', 'apples']
my_basket = ['oranges', 'apples', 'grapes', 'bananas']

for i, x in enumerate(my_fruit):
     if x in my_basket:
         print(f'Total {x} is {my_store[i]}')

# Total oranges is 1
# Total apples is 2
```

`enumerate` helps you iterate through list while keeping track of index so you could look up with that in `my_store`.